# Parse string to commandline-like array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I'm making an interactive app with Node that (obviously) takes user input. I have that much working, but some of the input has spaces, which a `.split(' ')` call would mess with.

Example of what's happening:

```
> foo "hello world" bar
['foo','"hello','world"','bar']
```

What I want to happen:

```
> foo "hello world" bar
['foo','hello world','bar']
```

I've tried looking for an npm package, but haven't had any luck.

**Edit**: I'm aware I can use regex, but I have no idea what the proper sequence would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
console.log(
  'foo "hello world" bar'.match(/"[^"]+"|\w+/g)
)
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/oZ0sK1/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

If you want to avoid `"` then use captured group regex with **[`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)**

```js
var str = 'foo "hello world" bar';
var reg = /"([^"]+)"|\w+/g,
  m, res = [];

while (m = reg.exec(str))
  res.push(m[1] || m[0])

console.log(res);
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/lW4vJ0/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use regex you may do like

```
'foo "hello world" bar'.replace('"',"").split(" ");
```

or to make sure to include a single quote input case you may use a simple regex as follows

```js
console.log('foo "hello world" bar'.replace(/("|')/g,"").split(" "));
```

Well ok here is my correction with regex. This one will only capture the text in between the quotes, excluding the quotes without using any capture groups. Since we don't use any capture groups a simple `String.prototype.match()` method can be utilized to resolve our array of wanted keys at one go without the looping.

```
[^"]+(?="(\s|$))|\w+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/sYn3TRhjN4wAKres)

```js
var reg = /[^"]+(?="(\s|$))|\w+/g,
    str = 'baz foo "hello world" bar whatever',
    arr = str.match(reg);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This outputs exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @Emillia Sorry my bad. The corrected code is attached below the misleading one. Sorry again.